# bootstrap modal should display data based on the clicked button row in a vue component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

Below is a code that explains how I fetch data from database

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">

          <thead>

              <tr><th>User ID</th><th>Account Number</th><th>Account Type</th><th>Account Status</th><th>Available Balance</th><th>Transactions</th></tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
         <tr v-for="account in data"
              :key="account.id"
              class="account-item">
           <td>{{ account.user_id }}</td><td>{{ account.account_number }}</td><td>{{ account.account_type.name }}</td><td>{{ account.account_status.status }}</td>
           <td>

            <div class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" onClick="bindData">Available Balance</div>

        </td><td><a :href="`transactions`"><div class="btn btn-info">Last 10 transactions</div></a></td></tr>

       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Below is a modal code

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" height="auto">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <span v-for="account in data">
    <span v-if="account.account_type.id == 2 && account.id==2">{{account.amount}}</span>
    <span v-else-if="account.account_type.id == 1 && account.id== 1">{{account.amount}}</span>
</span>

    </div>
  </div>
```

What I want is when a person clicks "Available Balance Button" only the balance of the concerned account to show up, not all balances like it is doing right now.

[image]

Comment: since you print both amount that mean u match more than once your if statment in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

- inside your table, loop you account data and assign every account.id to your data-target
- outside your table, loop again you account data and assign every account.id to every modal's id attribute.
- from there, I think each data will be reference correctly.

> screenshot

[image]

[you can see reference here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/iterating-v-for/)